# LWC - could not load __mocks__/sampledata (imported by root/app/app.js): request failed

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-dom

I have a requirement where I want to utilize the tree-grid LWC component. The sample example provided in the Component reference guide by the Salesforce for the same is not working. I'm getting the below exception:

Error Message: "Could not load **mocks**/sampleData (imported by root/basic/basic.js): request failed"
Component URL: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-tree-grid

Does anyone have any idea about this error or what data needs to be mapped in JS file in order to resolve this issue?

Comment: Could you add some code with which we can replicate the issue, a [playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground) link would be even better.

Comment: @Raul,The Salesforce sample example for the tree-grid is not working. 
Component URL: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-tree-grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just copied the column and grid data from the Lightning treegrid component and it worked for me.

### JS file

import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class TreeGridBasic extends LightningElement {

```
// definition of columns for the tree grid
gridColumns = [
    {
        type: 'text',
        fieldName: 'accountName',
        label: 'Account Name',
        initialWidth: 300
    },
    {
        type: 'number',
        fieldName: 'employees',
        label: 'Employees'
    },
    {
        type: 'phone',
        fieldName: 'phone',
        label: 'Phone Number'
    },
    {
        type: 'url',
        fieldName: 'accountOwner',
        label: 'Account Owner',
        typeAttributes: {
            label: { fieldName: 'accountOwnerName' }
        }
    },
    {
        type: 'text',
        fieldName: 'billingCity',
        label: 'Billing City'
    }
];

// data provided to the tree grid
gridData = [
    {
        "name": "123555",
        "accountName": "Rewis Inc",
        "employees": 3100,
        "phone": "837-555-1212",
        "accountOwner": "http://example.com/jane-doe",
        "accountOwnerName": "Jane Doe",
        "billingCity": "Phoeniz, AZ"
    },

    {
        "name": "123556",
        "accountName": "Acme Corporation",
        "employees": 10000,
        "phone": "837-555-1212",
        "accountOwner": "http://example.com/john-doe",
        "accountOwnerName": "John Doe",
        "billingCity": "San Francisco, CA",
        "_children": [
            {
                "name": "123556-A",
                "accountName": "Acme Corporation (Bay Area)",
                "employees": 3000,
                "phone": "837-555-1212",
                "accountOwner": "http://example.com/john-doe",
                "accountOwnerName": "John Doe",
                "billingCity": "New York, NY",
                "_children": [
                    {
                        "name": "123556-A-A",
                        "accountName": "Acme Corporation (Oakland)",
                        "employees": 745,
                        "phone": "837-555-1212",
                        "accountOwner": "http://example.com/john-doe",
                        "accountOwnerName": "John Doe",
                        "billingCity": "New York, NY"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "123556-A-B",
                        "accountName": "Acme Corporation (San Francisco)",
                        "employees": 578,
                        "phone": "837-555-1212",
                        "accountOwner": "http://example.com/jane-doe",
                        "accountOwnerName": "Jane Doe",
                        "billingCity": "Los Angeles, CA"
                    }
                ]
            },

            {
                "name": "123556-B",
                "accountName": "Acme Corporation (East)",
                "employees": 430,
                "phone": "837-555-1212",
                "accountOwner": "http://example.com/john-doe",
                "accountOwnerName": "John Doe",
                "billingCity": "San Francisco, CA",
                "_children": [
                    {
                        "name": "123556-B-A",
                        "accountName": "Acme Corporation (NY)",
                        "employees": 1210,
                        "phone": "837-555-1212",
                        "accountOwner": "http://example.com/jane-doe",
                        "accountOwnerName": "Jane Doe",
                        "billingCity": "New York, NY"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "123556-B-B",
                        "accountName": "Acme Corporation (VA)",
                        "employees": 410,
                        "phone": "837-555-1212",
                        "accountOwner": "http://example.com/john-doe",
                        "accountOwnerName": "John Doe",
                        "billingCity": "New York, NY",
                        "_children": [
                            {
                                "name": "123556-B-B-A",
                                "accountName": "Allied Technologies",
                                "employees": 390,
                                "phone": "837-555-1212",
                                "accountOwner": "http://example.com/jane-doe",
                                "accountOwnerName": "Jane Doe",
                                "billingCity": "Los Angeles, CA",
                                "_children": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "123556-B-B-A-A",
                                        "accountName": "Allied Technologies (UV)",
                                        "employees": 270,
                                        "phone": "837-555-1212",
                                        "accountOwner": "http://example.com/john-doe",
                                        "accountOwnerName": "John Doe",
                                        "billingCity": "San Francisco, CA"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },

    {
        "name": "123557",
        "accountName": "Rhode Enterprises",
        "employees": 6000,
        "phone": "837-555-1212",
        "accountOwner": "http://example.com/john-doe",
        "accountOwnerName": "John Doe",
        "billingCity": "New York, NY",
        "_children": [
            {
                "name": "123557-A",
                "accountName": "Rhode Enterprises (UCA)",
                "employees": 2540,
                "phone": "837-555-1212",
                "accountOwner": "http://example.com/john-doe",
                "accountOwnerName": "John Doe",
                "billingCity": "New York, NY"
            }
        ]
    },

    {
        "name": "123558",
        "accountName": "Tech Labs",
        "employees": 1856,
        "phone": "837-555-1212",
        "accountOwner": "http://example.com/john-doe",
        "accountOwnerName": "John Doe",
        "billingCity": "New York, NY",
        "_children": [
            {
                "name": "123558-A",
                "accountName": "Opportunity Resources Inc",
                "employees": 1934,
                "phone": "837-555-1212",
                "accountOwner": "http://example.com/john-doe",
                "accountOwnerName": "John Doe",
                "billingCity": "Los Angeles, CA"
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is something salesforce.com needs to fix. As far as I'm aware, this script isn't published anywhere, and has been missing since the beginning of the new docs. There's nothing you can do to fix the problem other than to submit a case to salesforce.com to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You will find problems with LWC components documentation in different places like examples, attributes description, default attributes, required attributes etc. I guess Salesforce has to streamline LWC documentation.

However, you can refer to AURA component documentation in most of the cases. For example, for your requirement, I created below example for `tree-grid` from [AURA documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:treeGrid/example) and it works perfectly fine:

HTML:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <lightning-tree-grid columns={gridColumns}
                             data={gridData}
                             expanded-rows={gridExpandedRows}
                             key-field="name">
        </lightning-tree-grid>
    </div>
</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api, track } from 'lwc';

export default class Poc extends LightningElement {

    connectedCallback() {
        this.gridColumns = [
            {
                type: 'text',
                fieldName: 'accountName',
                label: 'Account Name',
                initialWidth: 300
            },
            {
                type: 'number',
                fieldName: 'employees',
                label: 'Employees'
            },
            {
                type: 'phone',
                fieldName: 'phone',
                label: 'Phone Number'
            },
            {
                type: 'url',
                fieldName: 'accountOwner',
                label: 'Account Owner',
                typeAttributes: {
                    label: { fieldName: 'accountOwnerName' }
                }
            },
            {
                type: 'text',
                fieldName: 'billingCity',
                label: 'Billing City'
            }
        ];

        this.gridData = [
            {
                "name": "123555",
                "accountName": "Rewis Inc",
                "employees": 3100,
                "phone": "837-555-1212",
                "accountOwner": "http://example.com/jane-doe",
                "accountOwnerName": "Jane Doe",
                "billingCity": "Phoeniz, AZ"
            },

            {
                "name": "123556",
                "accountName": "Acme Corporation",
                "employees": 10000,
                "phone": "837-555-1212",
                "accountOwner": "http://example.com/john-doe",
                "accountOwnerName": "John Doe",
                "billingCity": "San Francisco, CA",
                "_children": [
                    {
                        "name": "123556-A",
                        "accountName": "Acme Corporation (Bay Area)",
                        "employees": 3000,
                        "phone": "837-555-1212",
                        "accountOwner": "http://example.com/john-doe",
                        "accountOwnerName": "John Doe",
                        "billingCity": "New York, NY",
                        "_children": [
                            {
                                "name": "123556-A-A",
                                "accountName": "Acme Corporation (Oakland)",
                                "employees": 745,
                                "phone": "837-555-1212",
                                "accountOwner": "http://example.com/john-doe",
                                "accountOwnerName": "John Doe",
                                "billingCity": "New York, NY"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "123556-A-B",
                                "accountName": "Acme Corporation (San Francisco)",
                                "employees": 578,
                                "phone": "837-555-1212",
                                "accountOwner": "http://example.com/jane-doe",
                                "accountOwnerName": "Jane Doe",
                                "billingCity": "Los Angeles, CA"
                            }
                        ]
                    },

                    {
                        "name": "123556-B",
                        "accountName": "Acme Corporation (East)",
                        "employees": 430,
                        "phone": "837-555-1212",
                        "accountOwner": "http://example.com/john-doe",
                        "accountOwnerName": "John Doe",
                        "billingCity": "San Francisco, CA",
                        "_children": [
                            {
                                "name": "123556-B-A",
                                "accountName": "Acme Corporation (NY)",
                                "employees": 1210,
                                "phone": "837-555-1212",
                                "accountOwner": "http://example.com/jane-doe",
                                "accountOwnerName": "Jane Doe",
                                "billingCity": "New York, NY"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "123556-B-B",
                                "accountName": "Acme Corporation (VA)",
                                "employees": 410,
                                "phone": "837-555-1212",
                                "accountOwner": "http://example.com/john-doe",
                                "accountOwnerName": "John Doe",
                                "billingCity": "New York, NY",
                                "_children": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "123556-B-B-A",
                                        "accountName": "Allied Technologies",
                                        "employees": 390,
                                        "phone": "837-555-1212",
                                        "accountOwner": "http://example.com/jane-doe",
                                        "accountOwnerName": "Jane Doe",
                                        "billingCity": "Los Angeles, CA",
                                        "_children": [
                                            {
                                                "name": "123556-B-B-A-A",
                                                "accountName": "Allied Technologies (UV)",
                                                "employees": 270,
                                                "phone": "837-555-1212",
                                                "accountOwner": "http://example.com/john-doe",
                                                "accountOwnerName": "John Doe",
                                                "billingCity": "San Francisco, CA"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },

            {
                "name": "123557",
                "accountName": "Rhode Enterprises",
                "employees": 6000,
                "phone": "837-555-1212",
                "accountOwner": "http://example.com/john-doe",
                "accountOwnerName": "John Doe",
                "billingCity": "New York, NY",
                "_children": [
                    {
                        "name": "123557-A",
                        "accountName": "Rhode Enterprises (UCA)",
                        "employees": 2540,
                        "phone": "837-555-1212",
                        "accountOwner": "http://example.com/john-doe",
                        "accountOwnerName": "John Doe",
                        "billingCity": "New York, NY"
                    }
                ]
            },

            {
                "name": "123558",
                "accountName": "Tech Labs",
                "employees": 1856,
                "phone": "837-555-1212",
                "accountOwner": "http://example.com/john-doe",
                "accountOwnerName": "John Doe",
                "billingCity": "New York, NY",
                "_children": [
                    {
                        "name": "123558-A",
                        "accountName": "Opportunity Resources Inc",
                        "employees": 1934,
                        "phone": "837-555-1212",
                        "accountOwner": "http://example.com/john-doe",
                        "accountOwnerName": "John Doe",
                        "billingCity": "Los Angeles, CA"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ];

        this.gridExpandedRows = ["123556", "123556-A", "123556-B", "123556-B-B", "123557"];

    }

}
```